# Defining a group in GAP without having its presentation

Tags: group-theory, gap, general-linear-group

I know how to define a group when we have its presentation in GAP by using FreeGroup command over the generators and then taking quotient over the relators, however what if I only have the group as a set, for instance let's say $O$ is the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, then I am interested in definig the follwing group in GAP.

$$G:=\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c\sqrt{-3} & d 
\end{bmatrix} \in PGL(2,O) | a,b,c,d \in O \}$$

Where $PGL(2,O)$ is the projective general linear group over $O$. So basically this is a subgroup of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

I don't know if it helps but note that $\sqrt{-3}$ is a prime in $O$ and also $O$ is the $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by $\{ 1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2} \}$.

How would one feed $G$ into GAP?

Eventually I want to find the presentation or at least the generators of the group if possible.

Comment: Usually you need to specify a (finite) set of generators in order to define a group in GAP. But even if you could define it, you would not be able to do much with it beyond the basic group operations on elements. AFAIK there is no known algorithm to find a finite set of generators of infinite groups of matrices and, if you were given a set of generators, then there is no known general algorithm for computing a finite presentation on those generators. These problems are probably theoretically unsolvable in general. Designing algorithms for infinite matrix groups is a hot research topic.

Comment: There are some things you can do with them, including deciding the Tits Alternative, and in the virtually solvable case you can do some structural calculations. In the other case, you can (in theory, at least) find a free subgroup, but you cannot in general decide whether a given group is free.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with $PGL(2,O)$. A paper by Swan (Generators and relations for certain special linear groups, Adv. Math, 1971, Cor. 6.2) gives you a presentation for $GL(2,O)$. Since it is your lucky day, a preprint of mine
https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04359
gives this presentation, and associated matrices in GAP explicitly. I have not tried, but expect it to be not too hard to find extra relations for $PGO$.

Now for your group. I believe it is the stabilizer in $PGO$ of the line spanned by $(0,1)$, modulo $(\sqrt{-3})$. Reduce the matrix generators modulo this ideal (i.e to matrices over $GF(9)$) and calculate the stabilizer in $PGO$ under action by these matrices. It has finite index, and you can use Reidemeister/Schreier (`IsomorphismFpGroup`) on this subgroup to find a presentation (including matrix generators).